# Javascript to make Post or Get call to a URL and return the text that's on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been trying to do this all morning I need to make either a POST or a GET call to this

URL http://cabbagetexter.com/send.php

I need it to return the text that's on the page, I know it can't be that difficult but I'm completely code blocked on this one, 
I've  tried using JQuerys .post and .get functions but I cant seem to return just the text on the page

any help would be appriciated

EDIT:
Ah ok so there's a technical reason for not being able to do it. balls, Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another possibility if you need to post calls to a page on another domain. Let's say your Javascript is being run from index.php. You might create a file called ctexter.php.
ctexter.php would use curl to make the post request to http://cabbagetexter.com/send.php, and would then output the response (the output from) send.php. So, if index.php makes an ajax call to ctexter.php, and ctexter.php is outputting the response from send.php, you have in effect achieved your goal.

You could make the curl post requests with this function:

```
function post_request($url, $data) {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if(is_object($value) || is_array($value)){
            $data[$key] = serialize($value);
        }
    }
    $output = array();
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result) {
        $output['status'] = "ok";
        $output['content'] = $result;
    } else {
        $output['status'] = "failure";
        $output['error'] = curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

where $url is (obviously) the url to post to, and $data is an associative array containing the data you want to submit.

Then on  ctexter.php you could do something like:

```
// Since we already built the post array in the
// ajax call, we'll just pass it right through
$response = post_request("http://cabbagetexter.com/send.php", $_POST);
if($response['status'] == "ok"){
    echo $response['content'];
}
else{
    echo "It didn't work";
}
```

Finally, hit ctexter.php using [JQuery .post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post("ctexter.php", 
{ 
    firstparamname: "firstparamvalue", 
    somethingelse: "llama" 
},
function(data) {
  alert("It worked! Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(function ($) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://cabbagetexter.com/send.php',
    type: 'text',
    success: function (response) {
      //do something with the text from the site
    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Obviously you need to host this script on the URL you are loading because of the same [origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: I wasn't aware of that limitation, I have the code I need written in Java which works perfectly, but I need it in JS now instead, Back to the drawing board I guess

Answer (score 2):

You are running into the cross domain limitation. You can only to a request to a page in the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on the same domain, you'd use some code like this:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("targetElementID").textContent = ajax.responseText;
    }
  }
ajax.open("GET","http://cabbagetexter.com/send.php",true);
ajax.send();
```

[Learn how to use AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started)

If not, then, sorry, you're out of luck because you'll run into the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make a request to that URL and get around the same origin policy. Put something like a PHP script on your own domain that makes a request to http://cabbagetexter.com/send.php and then call your own script from the javascript.

If your host supports PHP and cURL a script like this would do the job:

```
<?php
$url="http://cabbagetexter.com/send.php";
$post="";   
if(strstr($url,"?")){
    $split=explode("?",$url);
    $url=$split[0];
    $post=$split[1];
}
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 

if($post!=""){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
}else{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0); 
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
print $result;
?>
```